# Cast error for Remedy Web service in SOAPUI

Tags: xml, soapui, remedy

I am getting error while invoking Remedy Web Service "HPD_IncidentInterface_Create_WS" in SOAP UI. The SOAP version is 5.3.0. I have supplied all the mandatory fields.

Error:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body>
<soapenv:Fault>
<faultcode>soapenv:Server.userException</faultcode>
<faultstring>javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.axis.message.Text cannot be cast to org.w3c.dom.Element</faultstring>
<detail>
<ns1:hostname xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">cesremwebcrt03</ns1:hostname>
</detail>
</soapenv:Fault>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

XML Code:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:HPD_IncidentInterface_Create_WS">
<soapenv:Header>
    <urn:AuthenticationInfo>
    <urn:userName>"xxxx"</urn:userName>
    <urn:password>"xxxx"</urn:password>
    </urn:AuthenticationInfo>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
    <urn:HelpDesk_Submit_Service>
<urn:Action>Create</urn:Action>
<urn:Last_Name>Dhupar</urn:Last_Name>
<urn:First_Name>Vartika</urn:First_Name>
<urn:Status>Assigned</urn:Status>
<urn:Service_Type>User Service Request</urn:Service_Type>
    <urn:Impact>"4-Minor/Localized"</urn:Impact>
    <urn:Urgency>"4-Low"</urn:Urgency>
    <urn:Summary>XYZ</urn:Summary>
<urn:Reported_Source>Self Service</urn:Reported_Source>
    </urn:HelpDesk_Submit_Service>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Please help!

Comment: Have you tried validating the request before hitting it to the server? Just right click and validate from request editor.

Comment: Yes I have tried that and I am getting error as "Element-only content type cannot have text content"

Comment: Which is the same you got in the error message.Make sure you provide the correct / valid request. Is it a public wsdl? available externally in the internet?